# laravel trio name validation { full name } regx

Tags: php, regex, laravel

please any one know how can i implement full name (three part ) validation in laravel?

thanks in advance...

```
'name' =>  "required|regex:/^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[\p{Arabic}]|[_])*$/u|unique:guests,name,NULL,id,session_id," . $session->id,
```

`

Comment: Try `regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\p{Arabic}_]*$/u` or `regex:/^\w*$/u`

Comment: yes i know this but i need firstname middlename lastname 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done:)

```
                    'name' =>  "required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\p{Arabic}_]+ [a-zA-Z0-9\p{Arabic}_]+ [a-zA-Z0-9\p{Arabic}_]+$/u|unique:guests,name,NULL,id,session_id," . $session->id,
```

this the answer to implement three character of full name validations.